# How to export data from DynamoDB talbe by choosing time interval

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

As title reports, I would like to know if there is a way to export data from a table of DynamoDB AWS by doing a kind of *where condition* as you can do when selecting via SQL-syntax on a specific field key-value, like timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a DynamoDB export feature that supports conditional exporting, based on attribute values.

Your best option might be the new [Export to S3](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-export-amazon-dynamodb-table-data-to-data-lake-amazon-s3/) feature and then use Athena to filter the data via SQL.